# OpenVPN to bridged wifi

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I have a OpenVPN vpn server running on my Linksys/Tomato router. I can connect to all machines on my home network just fine, except for the following. I have several machines in another part of the house that I wanted to avoid running Cat5 to, so I took a spare Linksys/DDWRT router and set up a wifi bridge for these machines. If I am on a machine on the home network, I can connect to the admin interface on the bridge box, and I can see/access machines on the other side of the bridge. However, if I'm coming into the network via vpn, I cannot ping either the bridge machine nor any machines on the other side of the bridge. I understood that a bridged connection would not require another gateway, as the bridged machines are actually ON the original network.

- Openvpn network: 10.10.10.X
- Home Network: 192.168.240.X
- Wifi Bridge: 192.168.240.30

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you ping the machines directly connected to the router with tue VPN?  I don't think you'll be able to.

Comment: No, I can't ping the bridge machine (.30) or access (rdp/teamviewer/etc) any of the 3 machines on the other side of the bridge. I put the bridge up to avoid running cables across the house, and my wife's machine is one of those three and since I'm leaving home for about 3 weeks, I GOTTA be able to "teamview" her machine while I'm gone (she's pretty un-techy)....

Comment: Who is acting as DHCP server for the machines behind the DD-WRT router? RT router itself, or the Tomato router?

Comment: The 192.168.240.X addresses are issued by the dnsmasq on the Tomato. The bridge box has 192.168.240.30 set static.. The machines behind the bridge are supposed to get dhcp from the tomato, and they must be, since they work ok and have the addresses configured for them in tomato dnsmasq (based on mac address)..